# Can android NOW handle text to speech in a call?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have been browsing around for the last few days trying to find some stuff about text to speech in android. Allot of questions were answered in that time, however I am wondering about it possibly being used in a voice call.

I know that previous questions asked (In 2010) said no because it would not be audible to the other participant of the call. I am wondering if there is anything new that might allow this to work on the newer SDK's?

Here is to hoping!

Comment: Probably not, as the inability to inject into call audio is a limitation of the typical device architecture rather than the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access and manipulate the telephone service so it's not possible to play custom audio during a call.